# Twitter HBC API : Flag to check the status of the Streaming API Connection

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-hbc

How can I check if the twitter streaming API is connected or disconnected ? Is there any variable that stores this information ?

On Failure, Twitter Hosebird Client (hbc) internally tries to reconnect to the API. This information is logged. How can I retrieve the response status of the connection in a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old question, but since I ran into the same problem, I wanted to share my solution. Basically, what I do is listening for a `SocketTimeoutException` exception, and if it occurs, I set a boolean `isConnected = false`. Once I start receiving statuses again, I set that boolean back to `isConnected = true`. It is not the prettiest solution, but it works. Here my code for the Listener:

```
private StatusListener createListener() {
    return new StatusListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatus( Status tweet ) {
            if (!isConnected)
                isConnected = true;

            doSomething(tweet);
        }

        ( ... ) // Other @Override functions

        @Override
        public void onException( Exception ex ) {
            if ( ( ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException ) && isConnected ) {
                handleConnectionLoss();
                isConnected = false;
            } else {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
    };
}
```